# Fact tables with different level Date Dimension Data as Date Dimension Key

Tags: data-warehouse

I am a beginner in warehousing. I have two facts Which their names are sales and budget.
I can put days (Date Dimension key) in my sales Fact, but the table i have for budget can be just in month detail. so i don't know what i should do. would you please tell me what are the best practices in this case?

regards
Mana

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I generally find it easiest to store the month level data always on either the first/last day of the month.  This way, you can still aggregate up to month from date and compare sales & budget; and you will only store the budget value once a month as intended.  This would also help if down the road you're asked to store the budget data at the day level.

If you don't want to use this approach, then you would want to snowflake out your date dimension and have a separate  month dimension, and then your budget fact table can FK to this new dimension.